# Operator overloading - does side matters?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Say I implemented in my `Car` class the following operator:

```
Car operator*(int n, const Car& car);
```

And I have a `car` object of type `Car`:

Does  `Car car3 = car * 3;` yield the same result as  `Car car3 = 3 * car;`?

Or do I have to implement also

```
Car operator*(const Car& car, int n);
```

?

**EDIT:** The marked question hasn't helped me. In the marked question, the answer was given is using an operator he's implemented inside the class. I asked about operator that I implemented outside the class already.

Comment: This question hasn't helped me. please remove the mark so that I can get an answer

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have. This is because c++ doesn't force any simmetric rule on + operator as you are used to in math.
One way is to define the second definition inline and call the first.

Comment: No, the compiler won't try changing the order of arguments to see if something matches.

Comment: Oops i was wrong.  I change my answer

Comment: (I implemented `Car operator*(int n, const Car& car);` using a member-method of operator `+`. )........... So I have to have the non-member `Car operator*(int n, const Car& car);` and also a non-member `Car operator*(const Car& car,  int n);` that just return `n * car`?

Comment: As a member of the class, the class itself is the left hand side of the equation. as a global operator the first parameter is the left hand side, and the second is the right hand side. i.e: `LHS * RHS`.